# Functional language implementations of Production Grade data stores

Tags: scala, haskell, f#, erlang, clojure

There are many datastores written in Erlang, for example Riak, Dynomite, CouchDb, Scalaris, have I missed any?

I know that Java and C/C++ have also been used to write datastores (Cassandra, Hypertable, etc), but have any Datastores been written in any other functional languages such as F#, Scala, Haskell, Clojure, etc? The reason I am asking this (and many other functional programming and Erlang type questions) is to assess the feasibility of functional programming languages for real world projects.

As a side note it has been pointed out to me that I mean the actual implementation language of the datastore itself, and not the client language to access the datastore (ie: via ODBC).

Comment: To the first part: Yes. Mnesia comes with Erlang ;-)

Comment: I'll just mention that Scala, as opposed to the other languages you mention, is mostly an Object Oriented language, which happens to integrate Functional Language features. It's creator has recently called it "post-functional".

Comment: Ok,so I should probably remove Scala from the list if it is mostly OO?

Comment: Depends if you are asking whether Scala can build a good datastore where you can take advantage of its functional features (answer = yes), or whether it is practical to use a _purely_ functional approach to build a datastore (answer = you likely wouldn't make it 100% functional with Scala; other languages like Haskell are better test cases).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [Data.Tcache](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TCache) is a transactional cache with configurable persistence for Haskell.
2. [Elephant](http://common-lisp.net/project/elephant/) is a persistent object database for Common Lisp with full transaction semantics.
3. [CLSQL](http://clsql.b9.com/) - a SQL database for Common Lisp interface.
4. [AllegroCache](http://www.franz.com/products/allegrocache/) is a high-performance, dynamic object caching database system for Allegro Common Lisp.
5. [Spark-Scheme](http://spark-scheme.wikispot.org) comes with a built-in database and ODBC support.

Comment: I had a brief look at these. Spark seems the nicest, but has the worst website :) Do any of them work in clustered settings?

Comment: @Zubair Thanks for the favorable comment on Spark. That is my personal Lisp! About the website, do not have enough resources (all of time, money and personal) to create a better one.

Answer (score 3):

Your question puzzles me a little.  You ask about datastores written **in** a variety of languages.  Generally, when I program I look for a library or API to get and put data from and to the datastore in my chosen language.  What the underlying datastore is written in (if it's written in anything, some datastores are no more than file layouts) I do not care.

And on that basis a little Googling will turn up Haskell-to-ODBC libraries, and I imagine the other languages will have similar facilities.  I have no knowledge of these, so won't comment on their suitability for projects.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not explain it so clearly. I did mean the "underlying" data store as you pointed out.

Comment: Also, interesting point you made, which datastores are just file layouts, as I would like to evaluate them?

Comment: Really? Are you sure, that application data storage which doesn't copy data between processes of application and db doesn't have some benefits? Performance? In this case data store in specific language have big sense. Ordinal embedded db is not solution here because necessity of boiler plate. For example It is why mnesia in Erlang have big sense in some cases especially with native "stored procedures" and transactions (distribution involved).

Answer (score 3):

In one sense you have already answered your own question. The systems you mention, and others from the comments, **ARE** written in functional langauges and **ARE** definitely real world projects, so the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 3):

[FleetDB](http://fleetdb.org/) is schema-free database in Clojure.